# Can gganimate be implemented in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gganimate

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
      Date_Time = c(
        "2023-06-14 09:43:06",
        "2023-06-14 09:43:09",
        "2023-06-14 09:43:12",
        "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
        "2023-06-14 09:43:19"
      ),
      Specific_Heat_Capacity = c(159.65, 129.65, 190.65, 116.03, 180.71)
      
    )
df$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Date_Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This is my code which generates a circle where the values inside it changes based on Date_Time using gganimate :

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0), size = 60, shape = 21, fill = "#11141a", color = "#6cc3fa", stroke = 2) +

  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = paste("Specific Heat\n", Specific_Heat_Capacity)), color = "white", size = 5)+ 
  xlim(-4, 4) + ylim(-4, 4)

animated_plot <- plot +
  transition_time(Date_Time) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(animated_plot,   fps = 24)
```

Ouput:
[image]

How can I integrate the above code in Shiny

Comment: Do you want to have something reactive? Otherwise simply save the output as a GIF file and include it in the Shiny app.

Comment: I want it to be reactive

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - can plotly' be used here instead gganimate would that be more efficient

Comment: Thomas> I would use CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  what if I don't want the slider input in my Shiny App. Just want to display the gif

Comment: Thomas> See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way but it is slow. I'm not aware of another way.

I made the plot reactive to the choice of the size of the circle for the illustration.

The app saves the animation in a GIF file with `gganimate::anim_save` and then converts this file in base64 encoding, and then inserts the image. The slow part is `anim_save`.

```r
library(gganimate)
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)

df <- data.frame(
  Date_Time = c(
    "2023-06-14 09:43:06",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:09",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:12",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:19"
  ),
  Specific_Heat_Capacity = c(159.65, 129.65, 190.65, 116.03, 180.71)
)
df$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Date_Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Anim <- function(size) {
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 0, y = 0)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_void() +
    geom_point(
      aes(x = 0, y = 0), size = size, shape = 21, 
      fill = "#11141a", color = "#6cc3fa", stroke = 2
    ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        x = 0, y = 0, 
        label = paste("Specific Heat\n", Specific_Heat_Capacity)
      ), 
      color = "white", size = 5
    ) + 
    xlim(-4, 4) + ylim(-4, 4)
  
  plot +
    transition_time(Date_Time) +
    ease_aes('linear')
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("size", "Size", min = 40, max = 100, value = 80, step = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("animation")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  AnimB64 <- eventReactive(input[["size"]], {
    anim <- Anim(input[["size"]])
    tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".gif")
    anim_save(tmpFile, anim)
    dataURI(file = tmpFile, mime = "image/gif")
  })
 
  output[["animation"]] <- renderUI({
    tags$div(
      tags$img(src = AnimB64(), width="100%"),
      style = "width: 400px;"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit : a JavaScript+CSS solution

Since this is slow with the GIF, I would rather use a JavaScript+CSS solution. Something like that:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("animation", function(numbers) {
    var n = numbers.length;
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $("#numb").html(numbers[i]);
      i = (i + 1) % n;
    }, 500);
    $("#btn").on("click", function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
    });
  });
});
'

css <- '
.circle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 135px;
  width: 135px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#circletitle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#numb {
  font-size : 16px;
}
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  
  br(),
  
  actionButton(
    "btn",
    "Generate data"
  ),
  
  br(), br(),
  
  tags$span(
    class = "circle",
    tags$p(
      id = "circletitle",
      "Specific heat"
    ),
    tags$p(
      id = "numb"
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Numbers <- eventReactive(input[["btn"]], {
    round(cumsum(rgamma(20, 50, 1)), 2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(Numbers(), {
    session$sendCustomMessage("animation", Numbers())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Your a GOAT